# SAP OData Service Filter is not filtering

Tags: odata, azure-data-factory, sap-fiori, sap-gateway

I'm learning to get delta data from SAP Fiori sample gateway to Azure SQL by using Azure Data Factory and filter feature on OData service.
I'm using OData Service that exposed by Fiori sample, and one of the table sample is PurchaseOrders.

I tried like this:

> $filter=ChangedAt ge datetime '2020-09-08T22:00:00'

But it is still return all the records.

I found sap:filterable is false at metadata
[image]

Is that filterable false is made me cannot filter this?

Is there any other way to do delta extraction on OData rather than using filter?

Thank You

Comment: `sap:filterable` is purely informational. The actual support for the `$filter` query needs to be implemented by the OData service.

Answer (score 1):

As @Boghyon wrote above the "sap:filterable" is just an Annotation, which can help to build the UI. You have to check the DPC_EXT class's GET_ENTITY_SET method of the entity type that you try to filter. If filtering isn't implemented then (1.) in case of standard service you're more or less stuck (it cannot be filtered for a reason) (2.) in case of custom service you can implement filtering